# how to stack image to show in the background

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Please pardon me to post this.

i am working with this design more that 3 days now i can i get the actual design. all my effort design is been rejected.

i am trying to create this design.

the problem i have is the right and left box showing at the back of the image.

thanks in advance.

here is my code

> ```
> Container(
> child: Card(
> shape:RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius:
> BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
> ),
>                                                                     semanticContainer:true,
> clipBehavior:
>                                                                         Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
> child:Image(image:
>                                                                           NetworkImage(snapshot.data.docs[index].data()['picture'], ),
> fit: BoxFit.cover,), ),),);
> ```

[image]

Comment: do you want clickable splasheffect?

Comment: no not clickable splash effect. just to display the two shape at the back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Result**

[image]

If you like change, black shadow play with stops inside `gradient`. hope you will get the idea of doing it.

```
  stops: [.5, 1.0],
```

To AlignWidgte change this value`alignment: Alignment(-1, -1),`. For rotation change here. Better use slider or from `dart:math` use `pi`.

```
Transform.rotate(angle: -.166,
```

**Code snippet**

```
 
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  get imageWidth => 300;
  get imageHeight => 450;

  double sliderVal = 0.0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        buttonTheme: ButtonThemeData(
          textTheme: ButtonTextTheme.primary,
        ),
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Slider(
                value: sliderVal,
                onChanged: (v) {
                  setState(() {
                    sliderVal = v;
                    print(sliderVal);
                  });
                }),
            Container(
              width: imageWidth * 1.4,
              height: imageHeight * 1.1,
              child: Stack(
                children: [
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment(-1, -1),
                    child: Transform.rotate(
                      angle: -.166,
                      child: backImage(color: Colors.blue),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment(1, 1),
                    child: Transform.rotate(
                      angle: .128,
                      child: backImage(color: Colors.yellow),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Center(
                    child: mainImage(),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      // CustomSS(),
    );
  }

  backImage({required Color color, double? width, double? height}) {
    return Container(
      width: width ?? imageWidth,
      height: height ?? imageHeight,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: color,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
      ),
    );
  }

  SizedBox mainImage() {
    return SizedBox(
        width: imageWidth,
        height: imageHeight,
        child: ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
          child: Stack(
            fit: StackFit.expand,
            children: [
              Image.asset(
                "assets/me.jpg",
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
              Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  // borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                  gradient: LinearGradient(
                    begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                    end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                    stops: [.5, 1.0],
                    colors: [
                      Colors.transparent,
                      Colors.black87,
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Positioned(
                bottom: 30,
                left: 30,
                child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Row(
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            "Yeasin",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 22,
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            width: 8,
                          ),
                          Text(
                            "XX",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 22,
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 10,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        "Description",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 14,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ]),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: i mean the container showing at the back.. the right and lift back with different color

Comment: You could use a stack widget with two more containers that are stacked behind each other differently.

Comment: i added a slider so that you add the value you want

Answer (score 1):

```
Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        height: double.infinity,
        width: double.infinity,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            begin: Alignment.topLeft,
            end: Alignment.bottomRight,
            colors: [
              Colors.pinkAccent,
              Colors.yellowAccent,
            ],
          ),
        ),
        child: Stack(
          children: [
                        Positioned(
              left: 70,
              // right: 40,
              top: 40,
              child: Transform.rotate(
                angle: pi - 3.30,
                child: Container(
                  // transform: ,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                    color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.2),
                  ),
                  height: 200,
                  width: 150,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              left: 130,
              // right: 150,
              top: 78,
              child: Transform.rotate(
                angle: pi + 3.30,
                child: Container(
                  // transform: ,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                    color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.6),
                  ),
                  height: 190,
                  width: 150,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              left: 0,
              right: 0,
              top: 50,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 100.0),
                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                    color: Colors.white,
                    image: DecorationImage(
                      image: NetworkImage("https://picsum.photos/200/300"),
                      fit: BoxFit.fill
                    ),
                  ),
                  height: 220,
                  width: 100,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

[image]